# xAuth Objective-C implementation on Foursquare

Tags: iphone, objective-c, foursquare, xauth

nHi,

I am trying to create an iPhone app that uses xAuth to connect to Foursquare. Does anybody have any examples they can direct me to?

I know there are a lot of twitter implementations of xAuth out there, but I'm having trouble adapting them to foursquare.

If you have an OAuth implementation, instead, that would be great too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Found a good example: https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/tree/master/FoursquareIntegration